# Weird segfault in CodeBlocks with c++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, segmentation-fault

The C++11 standard includes a new method to hardcode vectors. And using it, I hardcoded this data in `int main()`:

```
std::vector <std::vector <double> > A = {{1, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 5, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 7, 3}, {1, 7, 9, 1}};
```

however, when i add this line:

```
std::vector <std::vector <double> > b = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}};
```

under the first line, CodeBlocks/GCC says: `internal compiler error: Segmentation fault`

why?

Comment: Time to update your compiler!

Comment: C++11 support is experimental, still, with GCC.

Comment: Best call this "literal initialisation" or something, not "hard-coding"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internal compiler error means that gcc crashed during the compilation process. That looks like a gcc bug. Which gcc version do you use?

Per your comment, the solution is very likely to upgrade your compiler.

Comment: @calccrypto: Then you should upgrade your compiler to one that isn't broken.